# Pulsating text on iphone

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, safari

I'm browsing my new website from iphone ( Both Safari and Chrome ) and i keep seing **pulsating text** ! i tried different  iphones and i still see the text weirdly pulsating.

1. I removed all the javascript files, the same thing.
2. I made few CSS adjustement, nothing.

Does this happen to anybody before, because i didn't find any similar issues.

http://uniteworks.com/demo.html

I'll appreciate any assistance.

Comment: In my test website i can't see the problem http://uniteworks.com/sandbox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. It turned out the cause was the css transition property on our links:

```
-o-transition:.3s;
-ms-transition:.3s;
-moz-transition:3s;
-webkit-transition:.3s;
transition:.3s;
```

It seems that the iPhone handles hover events in a strange way that caused this strange pulsation. We turned off transitions on mobile and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help ! it seems the same issue here.